# Using Jest with Puppeteer : Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_4kq3tptqc is not defined

Tags: javascript, web-scraping, automated-tests, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm trying to get description of a page with Puppeteer, I have a high order function that provides the page object to this function :

```
export const checkDescription = async page => {
  const metaDescription = await page.$eval(
    'meta[name="description"]',
    description => description.getAttribute("content")
  );
  return metaDescription;
};
```

the function works as expected.
Then, I'm using Jest to run a test.

```
const testDescription = await withPage(checkDescription)(URL);
expect(typeof testDescription).toBe("string");
```

I have the following err:

```
  Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_4kq3tptqc is not defined
      at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:2:41
      at ExecutionContext.evaluateHandle 
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    -- ASYNC --
      at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> 
      at ExecutionContext.evaluate
      at ExecutionContext.<anonymous> 
      at ElementHandle.$eval
      at <anonymous>
      at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
    -- ASYNC --
```

If I just paste the function in the jest file, then it works as expected

Comment: What is `withPage` ?

Comment: this is just a high order function, it works as expected

Comment: I had the same issue using Playwright with Jest. @oneralon's answer solved it for me.

Answer (score 9):

If you need to collect the coverage, it can be fixed by adding `/* istanbul ignore next */` before browser contexted functions (lines with `.eval`) to prevent istanbul coverage injects.

Comment: The relevant discussion at Istanbul's GitHub: https://github.com/istanbuljs/nyc/issues/514

Comment: I had the same problem with playwright, and perhaps not surprisingly, this fixed the issue there too.

Answer (score 6):

In puppeteer, while running tests, istanbul was inserting the following :

```
 /* istanbul ignore next */cov_4kq3tptqc.f[7]++;
                    cov_4kq3tptqc.s[19]++;
```

Was fixed by adding `config.collectCoverage = false;` to the `jest.config`

Comment: Not only does `config.collectCoverage = false` fixes break the above error but also the breakpoint of vscode in debugging mode (typescript) now works when

Answer (score 0):

Placing /* istanbul ignore next */ within the evaluate function resolved the problem effectively.

Didn't work:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */
const result = await page.evaluate((el, attr) => el.getAttribute(attr), el, attr)
```

Worked:

```
const result = await page.evaluate(/* istanbul ignore next */(el, attr) => el.getAttribute(attr), el, attr)
```