# Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_77g31rban is not defined in Jest Puppeteer test

Tags: javascript, jestjs, puppeteer

I'm using the code in several projects and it works fine:

```
await page.$eval("input[id*='virtual_course']", elem => elem.click())
```

Except in one project, I get the following error:

```
Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_77g31rban is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:7
```

I'm using the same version of all libraries and all projects so not sure why there would be the difference?

Comment: Hard to say without the site. Every site is different and there are no silver bullets. Just because something works on one site doesn't mean it'll work on others. `cov_77g31rban` seems totally unrelated to your code, for starters.

Comment: Here's some more information. I noticed that the error only seems to happen when I'm running the function as a test using Jest. The error happens with every instance of $eval. It's also happening with this line:

const test = await page.$eval(`#courseID`, el => el.textContent.trim())

Here's the error

Error: Evaluation failed: ReferenceError: cov_77g31rban is not defined
    at __puppeteer_evaluation_script__:3:7

    at ExecutionContext._evaluateInternal (/Users/et/src/WebstormProjects/sal/node_modules/puppeteer/src/common/ExecutionContext.ts:273:13)

Answer (score 0):

Once I realized that running through Jest was the culprit, I found [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272295/using-jest-with-puppeteer-evaluation-failed-referenceerror-cov-4kq3tptqc-is) which fixed the problem.

In Puppeteer, while running tests, istanbul was inserting the following:

```
/* istanbul ignore next */cov_4kq3tptqc.f[7]++;
                   cov_4kq3tptqc.s[19]++;
```

This was fixed by adding `config.collectCoverage = false;` to the jest.config.